# ActionController::RoutingError in Bank_accounts#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I seem to be getting a routing error within my Rails project each time I try access the index for "Bank Accounts". I'm quite new to Rails so this should probably be a simple error. If I've missed anything I apologise.

**Errors I'm getting:**

ActionController::RoutingError in Bank_accounts#index
Showing app/views/bank_accounts/index.html.erb where line #21 raised

**This is the line of code that Rails doesn't seem to like:**

```
<td><%= link_to 'Transaction Details', bank_account_transaction_path(bank_account) %>  </td>
```

**Routes file:**

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
map.resources :bank_accounts, :has_many => [:transactions]

map.root :controller => "bank_accounts"

map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

**Index view for Bank Accounts**

```
<% @bank_accounts.each do |bank_account| %>
<tr>
<td><%=h bank_account.account_number %></td>
<td><%=h bank_account.holders_name %></td>
<td><%=h bank_account.overdraft_limit %></td>
<td><%=h bank_account.current_balance %></td>
<td><%=h bank_account.active %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show', bank_account %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_bank_account_path(bank_account) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Transaction Details', bank_account_transaction_path(bank_account) %>      </td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', bank_account, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `rake routes` (or `bundle exec rake routes`)?

Comment: Hi Scott, I'm new to Rails, I presume this is run through the Rails console? I've tried running it via the Rails console, but all I get is "NameError: undefined local variable or method `routes' for #<Object:0x1b576f8>" - so I presume I was wrong...

Comment: You would want to do it from the command line in the project folder for your app (same place the Gemfile is). I am sorry I missed this but Xavier may have hit on the issue in his answer below.

Comment: I have it working with Xavier's solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the Rails naming convention is that if you want to link to an index of nested resources, you need to use the plural:

```
bank_account_transactions_path(bank_account)
```

And if you want to link to a particular nested resource, use the singular and pass in the nested resource ID as a second argument:

```
bank_account_transaction_path(bank_account, txnid)
```

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548009/rails-link-to-routes-and-nested-resources) has an example of a cleaner syntax - you might like that better.

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should
Resources :bank_accounts do
member 'transaction', :method=> :get
End

In your index
transaction_bank_account_path(account)

Controller
Def transaction
....
End