# Seeking a better way to define my Rails routes/paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 main components to my application, Users and Properties.  The URL should be structured like: hostname.com/users/:user_id/properties/:property_id.  I believe I've made a configuration error somewhere, because Rails never recognizes "property_path" or any of its variants, and I've had to hard code them in to get the redirects to work.

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :users do
    resources :properties
  end
```

**users/show.html.erb** - Notice I had to hard code the path, instead of simply linking to "i"

```
<% @user.properties.each do |i| %>
<li><%= link_to "#{i.address}", "/users/#{@user.id}/properties/#{i.id}" %></li>
<% end %>
```

How can I better define my routes so that I can link above to just "i", which would represent the "properties_path", and would auto redirect to that show page?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548009/rails-link-to-routes-and-nested-resources for answer

Comment: thanks @atomAltera, and my mistake for missing that one.  This seems to definitely be a duplicate question then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to hardcode it. You can do:

```
<% @user.properties.each do |property| %>
  <li><%= link_to property.address, [@user, property] %></li>
<% end %>
```

Yes, it's that simple. For more information, you can go to [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware you could link like that at all, but now it totally makes sense.  With that structure, Rails will look for the 'property' path only if it's associated with @user.  Thanks Marek, I'll accept the question in 7 minutes when it allows me