# how can i set my links to an specific item in ruby on rails 5 with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Well i have an application in Rails 5. My problem is that i have nested resources for example `user/1/companies/1`
all the companies that every user owns are listed in the show action of the user. Everything works perfect until the point where i want that every user click in their company name (using the helper link_to) but all the companies are redirect to the first company that the user created

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users

  resources :users do 
    resources :companies do
      resources :parts
    end
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

userscontroller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController     
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @company = @user.companies.find_by(params[:company_id])
    @companies = current_user.companies.all.order('created_at DESC') if current_user    
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% @companies.each do |company|%>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><%=company.id %></th>
      <td><%=link_to company.name, user_company_path(@user, @company)  %></td>
      <td><%= company.description %></td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<% end  %>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please format your code and also try to remove unneccessary code, most of it is not needed to answer the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You should change this

```
user_company_path(@user, @company)
```

to

```
user_company_path(@user, company)
```

in `show.html.erb`.

References: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549211/1776169